# How can I gain access to methods of FilePond

Tags: reactjs, filepond

I am new to FilePond and I want to invoke a method thereof, quite externally. Say, I have the following scenario:

```js
<button onClick={(e)=>{
// open filePond browse 
}>Browse filepond manually</button>

<FilePond ... />
```

When the user clicks button, I want the FilePond be openned.

Within FilePond documents, I see there is a [*browse*](https://pqina.nl/filepond/docs/patterns/api/filepond-instance/#methods) method. I feel I should call it but I don't know how to do so in ReactJs. Is there any solutions to do so?

Answer (score 1):

The `<FilePond/>` component exposes the FilePond instance methods, so if you get a `ref` to the `<FilePond/>` component you can run the functions on it.

See this article on refs: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactcreateref

Answer (score 0):

Building on @Rik answer, this is how i manually triggered FilePond `browse` method:

1. Create a ref

```
const filePondRef = useRef(null);
```

2. Add to FilePond component

```
<FilePond
 ref={filePondRef}
 files={photo}
 onupdatefiles={(files) => setPhoto(files)}
 acceptedFileTypes={['.png', '.jpeg']}
/>
```

3. Trigger `browse` method

```
<button
 onClick={() => filePondRef?.current?.browse()}
>
 Select image
</button>
```